# Using constants in Objective-C results in errror

Tags: objective-c

In my application I want to use some constant strings.
I've created `Constant.h` and put some values inside:

```
extern NSString * const CAR_PLAY;
extern NSString * const CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY;
extern NSString * const DISCONNECTED_FROM_CAR_PLAY;
```

Then, I've created `Constants.m` file and put the actual value inside:

```
NSString * const CAR_PLAY = @"CarPlay";
NSString * const CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY = @"Conencted_To_CarPlay";
NSString * const DISCONNECTED_FROM_CAR_PLAY = @"Disconnected_from_CarPLay";
```

In my `AppDelegate` I imported `Constants.h`:

```
#import "Constants.h"
```

When I tried to use one of the values for example:

```
[string isEqualToString:CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY];
```

I got an error saying `Undefined symbol: _CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY`.

What is wrong with my implementation? What is the correct way to use constatns?

Comment: It should be fine though. Did you add the .m to your target? I don't know if that's really the case in your real variables, but `Connected_` instead of `Conencted_` should be better, no?

Comment: From the code alone it's impossible to spot any specific problem. Does the error refer to the place where you expect the constant to be used (`referenced from:` part)? Do you have the `Constants.m` among the compile sources in the `Build Phases` of your target? Don't your constant names clash with some other constants (i can't see any name prefix to avoid that)?

Comment: Does not the const leyword be before the type  «NSString *» declaration ?

Comment: @PtitXav `NSString` has immutable interface, it would not make any difference and. And `const` **must** be on the right side of the asterisk to maintain constness of the pointers.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind : thanks for the input. BTW, I tested and the code has no problem (xCode 13.4.1) the problem must be in some missing import/include

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
% cc -framework Foundation  -o constants constants.m appdelegate.m
% cat constants.h
extern NSString * const CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY;
% cat constants.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString * const CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY = @"Conencted_To_CarPlay";
% cat appdelegate.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "constants.h"
int main() {
    NSLog(@"now: %s", [CONNECTED_TO_CAR_PLAY UTF8String]);
    return 0;
}
% ./constants
2022-09-14 18:31:58.518 constants[94914:1189470] now: Conencted_To_CarPlay
```